# Can't add edges to a networkx graph

Tags: python, visualization, networkx, graph-theory

So I've never used Networkx before so this might be basic. I'm currently using a couple functions to output dictionaries of simple graphs e.g. the cycle graph. For example, if I run that function for n = 5 I get the dictionary: {1: [5, 2], 2: [1, 3], 3: [2, 4], 4: [3, 5], 5: [4, 1]}.

I've started trying to use Networkx to visualise these and have the following function to output edges of the graph:

```
def generate_edges(graph): # generate edges of the graph

    edges = []

    for node in graph: # checks each node

        for neighbour in graph[node]:

            edges.append((node,neighbour)) # returns the node,neighbour pair as an edge

    return edges
```

I'm then using the following function to create the network visualisation:

```
def visualise(graph):

    edges = generate_edges(graph)
    nodes = list(graph.keys())

    G = nx.graph
    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    G.nodes(data=True)
    nx.write_graphml(G,'so.graphml')
    print(nx.info(G))

    return G

graph = generate_simplegraph('cycle',10)
visualise(graph)
```

where the 'cycle' is the type of graph and the 10 is the number of nodes. I keep getting the error:

**module 'networkx.classes.graph' has no attribute 'add_edges_from'**

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error and how to fix it please? All I want to do is visualise the network. Also, I have imported networkx as nx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

graph should be a class in networkx I believe.

```
G=nx.Graph()
```

not:

```
G = nx.graph
```